# How to safely split a string and check for both values

Tags: scala

If I do this it throws an exception:

```
"".split('=')(1)
```

Is there a idomatic way to do this kind of operation safely in scala?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
scala> "".split('=').lift(1)
res0: Option[String] = None

scala> "a=b".split('=').lift(1)
res2: Option[String] = Some(b)
```

Note that `Array` after implicit conversion is a partial function from indices to values. You can `lift` any partial function, so that instead of a value, or an exception if it is not defined at the given argument, it will return `Some(value)` or `None` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:

```
s.split("=") match {
  case a@Array(_, _) =>
    Some(a)
  case _ =>
    None
}
```

But normally you add some logic:

```
s.split("=") match {
  case Array(x, y) =>
    Some(x.toInt * y.toDouble)
  case _ =>
    None
}
```